# Why aren't my if statements working?

Tags: list, if-statement, clojure

I'm extremely new to Clojure and very new to functional programming. I'm expecting this to return True or False but it's just infinitely recursing and it doesn't seem to be hitting true at all.

My test data set is this:

```
(def y (list 1 2 3 4)) ; and I'm passing in 2 for X.


(defn occursIn [x y]
    (if (= y nil) 
        "False"
        (if (= x first y )
            "True"  
            (occursIn x (rest y))
        )
    )

)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, and please pay attention to the recommended way to format your code - don't leave lonely parentheses on a line by themselves, they're *not* like `{}` in other programming languages:

```
(defn occursIn [x y]
  (if (empty? y) 
      "False"
      (if (= x (first y))
          "True"  
          (occursIn x (rest y)))))
```

You forgot to call `first` on the `y` list, like this:

```
(first y)
```

Also, notice that the base case isn't working as you expected. Use this test instead:

```
(empty? y)
```

For completeness' sake, here's a more idiomatic way to write the same procedure - but beware of the edge case pointed by @omiel in the comments, this won't work if `x` is `false` or `nil`:

```
(defn occursIn [x y]
  (if (some #(= x %) y)
      "True"
      "False"))
```

An even better solution, free from the edge case - as suggested by @mange in the comments:

```
(defn occursIn [x y]
  (if (every? #(not= x %) y)
      "False"
      "True"))
```

Comment: Oh man! That actually makes sense! I guess I was just getting a bit overwhelmed. Ill try this really quick.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Also, I was unaware that I needed to use empty instead of nil?

Comment: @Agent404 great! it was my pleasure :) also, be sure to check that last update to my answer.

Comment: Can you explain "some", "#", and the "%"?

Comment: @Agent404 this: `#( … )` is shorthand for an anonymous function, in this case it's a predicate that compares one value against `x` to see if they're equal. `%` is the parameter in the function. And `some` takes care of applying the function to each element in the list, until one is found that returns true for the given predicate.

Comment: Wow! Clojure does some pretty neat things with its syntax! Thanks again Oscar!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez In the above function, `some` returns the first element of `y` equal to `x`, so it won't work if `x` is `false` or `nil` (i.e. `x` is false-y): it will return `"False"` whether `y` contains `x` or not.

Comment: To solve the `false`/`nil` thing you could use `(defn occurs-in [x y] (if (every? #(not= x %) y) "False" "True")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Oscar's answer is correct and helpful, but I just thought I'd provide an alternate answer which demonstrates how to make a function which is closer to your original function, while still being relatively idiomatic clojure:

```
(defn occurs-in [needle haystack]
  (if-let [[head & tail] (seq haystack)]
    (if (= needle head)
      "True"
      (recur needle tail))
    "False"))
```

In this case I've:

- used destructuring to extract `head`/`tail` instead of using `first`/`rest` on a sequence.
- used `if-let` to bind those names only if `haystack` is non-empty (that is, if `(seq haystack)` is truthy).
- used `recur` instead of `occurs-in` to ensure that this function will be compiled to use tail call elimination, so it calls itself again without using an additional stack frame.

  This may not be an issue for small inputs, but it's essential to make it work for calls like `(occurs-in 1000000 (range))`

In terms of idiomatic naming, see that I've used `occurs-in` instead of `occursIn`: generally lisps use hyphens (`lisp-case`) instead of camel case (`camelCase`) for names.

Answer (score 2):

Before we do anything else, let's replace `"True"` with boolean `true` and `"False"` with boolean `false`. The reason for doing this will become apparent.

The fundamental problem is that `rest` never returns `nil`. It returns the empty list `()` instead. And `(rest ())` is `()`. So you get an endless sequence of recursive calls that ultimately blow the top off the stack.

`next` does return `nil` where `rest` returns `()`. So use `next` instead of `rest` and at least we get an answer:

```
(def aList (list 1 2 3 4))

(defn occursIn [x y]
    (if (= y nil) 
        false
        (if (= x first y)
            true
            (occursIn x (next y))
        )
    )
)

(occursIn 2 aList)
; false
```

... but the wrong answer. Why? As @OscarLopez says, you are missing parentheses around `first y` to call `first` upon the argument `y`. As it stands,

```
(= x first y)
```

tests whether `x`, `first`, and `y` are all equal. There is only one way this can happen:

```
(occursIn first first)
; true
```

... not what we want. So, let's call `first` instead of comparing it:

```
(defn occursIn [x y]
    (if (= y nil) 
        false
        (if (= x (first y))
            true
            (occursIn x (next y))
        )
    )
)

(occursIn 2 aList)
; true
```

It works.

Actually, the base case does work:

```
(occursIn 2 ())
; false
```

... but only because the `next` call turns `()` into `nil`: queasy.

And it does misfire searching for `nil`:

```
(occursIn nil ())
; true
```

... because `(first ())` returns `nil` and `nil` pretends to be `()` when asked to be a sequence (this is called *nil punning*), so `(first nil)` is `nil`.

So, again following Oscar, we had better test whether `y` is empty, not whether it is `nil`:

```
(defn occursIn [x y]
    (if (empty? y) 
        false
        (if (= x (first y))
            true
            (occursIn x (next y))
        )
    )
)

(occursIn nil ())
; false
```

The logic is now correct. Let's make it clearer by using `and` and `or` instead of `if`s with explicit `true` and `false` results (a code smell, in my view):

```
(defn occursIn [x y]
    (and (not (empty? y))
         (or (= x (first y))
             (occursIn x (next y))
         )
    )
)
```

The code reads easily now. It is to do this that we used the proper boolean values.

Only two more changes:

- If you look up `empty?`, you'll find that `(empty? y)` means `(not
  (seq y))`, so `(not (empty? y))` means `(not (not (seq y)))`, which is
  equivalent to `(seq y)`.
- The recursive call to `occursIn` is the last thing that happens: it
  is said to be in *tail position*. We can therefore replace it by
  `recur`. This consumes no stack, so puts no limit on the length of
  the sequence that can be searched.

So we end up with ...

```
(defn occursIn [x y]
    (and (seq y)
         (or (= x (first y))
             (recur x (next y))
         )
    )
)
```